# ArcObjects modify Map Scale

Tags: arcobjects, scale

I'm trying to modify the scale of the map so I can further export to pdf.

The mxd document has a fixed map scale option set. The initial value is 250 and final is still 250 unchanged. The code looks like this:

```
mxdPath = GetResPath() + "\\Template.mxd"
mapDoc = NewObj(esriCarto.MapDocument, esriCarto.IMapDocument)
mapDoc.Open(mxdPath)

pActiveView = mapDoc.ActiveView
pFeatureLayer = pGPUtil.OpenFeatureLayerFromString(path)
pLayer = CType(pFeatureLayer, esriCarto.ILayer)

pMap = mapDoc.Map[0]
pMap.MapScale = 500.0 #this will change the value, but the mxd just doesn't care
pMap.AddLayer(pLayer)
pActiveView.Refresh()
outDocumentPath = GetTempPath() + "\\Document.mxd"
mapDoc.SaveAs(outDocumentPath)
mapDoc.Close()
```

I also want to mention that setting the Extent through pActiveView.Extent works, but it's harder to get an extent out of a scale

**EDIT 1:** I have already tried with both Automatic and fixed, on Automatic if I try to get the property it will throw and Exception and if I try to set the property nothing happens also.

**EDIT 2:** It seems the ArcObjects does actually modify the MapScale when setting the property, but it won't save this option when calling `mapDoc.Close()`. The workaround was to load the `.mxd` again using ArcPy and setting the `.activeDataFrame.scale` property.

I hope this is helpful for people having related problems!

Comment: Have you tried setting the value on directly on the IDisplayTransformation object. Perhaps that will work despite supposedly referring to the same data: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjectsonline/componenthelp/esricore/IDisplayTransformation_ScaleRatio.htm

Comment: I have just tried it and that doesn't work either

Comment: Can you just disable the fixed map scale option for that mxd?  That should allow you to set the scale as shown in your code.

Comment: I have already tried with both Automatic and fixed, on Automatic if I try to get the property it will throw and Exception and if I try to set the property nothing happens also.

Comment: Can you post the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available."

Comment: Are you running this code from Python?

Comment: That is *really* odd, I'm using pretty much the same objects, except I use mapDoc.FocusMap, and the same methods to set the map scale and it works for me, it could have something to do with the map being only *half baked* as it's not fully opened. Does the pActiveView.Extent change when you set the map scale?

Comment: @MichaelStimson could you please upload a snippet in Python where you modify this scale ?

Comment: Not python, VB.net. Your code is ArcObjects. If you're doing this in python try opening the MXD with arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(outDocumentPath) and set DataFrame.scale then re-save the document http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/  I know it's double handling but I suspect the object isn't completely ready to set the map scale; I had a similar problem opening a map document from IGXObject, I had to DoEvents() to allow the document to fully open before setting any map elements.